# How can I create multiple independent conversations between two users in XMPP Server?

Tags: xmpp, chat, node-xmpp, stanza.io

I want to create a chat where multiple independent conversations can be created between two users in my XMPP Server (MongooseIM).

I tried to do it with threads but it does not work since when I log in if the user has messages offline, the server marks the messages as read. Or if I send a message to the other user, the server marks all messages as read.

Do you think it would be the solution to use MUC?, or can I do it without using MUC?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Maybe using two separate accounts would work best in that case? MUC could be a solution, but this has it's own set of problems (especially offline messages)

Comment: I've tried two separate accounts, but the problem is that to receive notifications you have to log in both accounts, and I want to have a common inbox. MUC Light does not receive offline messages?